# Rewriting statements without using quantifiers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Let $P$ and $Q$ be predicates on the set $S$, where $S$ has two elements, say, $S = \{a, b\}$. Then the statement $∀xP(x)$ can also be written in full detail as $P(a) ∧ P(b)$. Rewrite each of the statements below in a similar fashion, using  $P$, $Q$, and logical operators, but without using quantifiers.

(a) $∀x∀y(P(x)∨Q(y))$

(b) $∃xP(x)∧∃xQ(x)$

(c) $∃x∃y(P(x)∧Q(y))$

(d) $∀x∃y(P(x)∧Q(y))$

I managed to find a solution for (a) and (b) but now I'm stuck on (c) and (d).

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the universal set is $S = \{a, b\}$, you can write $\exists x P(x)$ as $P(a) \vee P(b)$. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
\exists x \exists y (P(x) \wedge P(y)) &\Longleftrightarrow \exists x ((P(x) \wedge P(a)) \vee (P(x) \wedge P(b))) \\
&\Longleftrightarrow (P(a) \wedge P(a)) \vee (P(a) \wedge P(b)) \vee (P(b) \wedge P(a)) \vee (P(b) \wedge P(b))
\end{align*}
$$
by simply eliminating the existential quantifiers one by one. Can you do the last one yourself?

Answer (score 1):

We can express $\exists y(P(x)\land Q(y))$ as $$\tag1(P(x)\land Q(a))\lor (P(x)\land Q(b)),$$ which can by simplified to $$\tag2P(x)\land (Q(a)\lor Q(b)).$$ If you manged to solve (a) and (b), I am sure you can finish (c) and (d) by eliminating the $\exists x$ or $\forall x$ prepended to either (1) or (2).